# How to change memory units format in R? e.g. bytes to megabytes

Tags: r

the question is quite simple but I haven't find any answers on google or in the `?options` function of R.

I actually updated my **R** and **RStudio** version and since then, each time I use a function such as `memory.limit()`, the output is given to me as bytes instead of megabytes or gigabytes. This is not a real problem but I find more convenient to read 32 000MB instead of 32000000000 bytes.

I know this is probably in some options but even looking at `?memory.limit` it seems there's no units or format as arguments.

As far as coding goes I want (MB) :

```
memory.limit()
32000
```

instead of (bytes) :

```
memory.limit()
32000000000
```

Please note that I don't want a function converting bytes to megabytes, I simply want to change the print behavior of R in this regard.

Thank you.

Comment: Actually, I see different results in RStudio versus running Rgui or R in a terminal.  Apparently this is an RStudio bug.

Comment: Apparently this has been fixed in recent RStudio builds:  see https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/4986

Comment: Thanks for the comment, no I'm not looking at a different function, like I said I have 2 computer and the one not updated is getting the ouput I desire. I'll take a look at the link, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `format()`.

```
format(memory.limit(), units = "Mb")
```

Also good to know:

```
format(thing_to_format, units = 'auto')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am actually aware of using the ``format()`` function this way but this is not what I am looking for. I simply want to use ``memory.limit()`` and have MB or GB has units without having to specify it every time. I don't know why the print behavior of this function changed after the update of R.

Comment: Make your own function.  `mem_lim <- function(){format(memory.limit(), units = 'Mb')}

Comment: Thanks, I know I can do it this way but that's the point, I shouldn't have too. Base R used to do it just fine. On my other computer, it is still working just fine, so I just want to know how to change that back.